# why is my class not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Guys i'm scratching my head for this problem. As, i get this error from my openshift log

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function totalids() on a
>   non-object in
>   /var/lib/openshift/573dc0da2d5271d357000294/app-root/runtime/repo/st&com.php
>   on line 46, referer: http://express-pad4u.rhcloud.com/

And doing var_dump on $conn and $project from dbconfig.inc.php file in st&com.php gives the following message:

> object(PDO)#1 (0) { }  object(projecteg)#2 (4) {
>   ["_db":"projecteg":private]=> object(PDO)#1 (0) { } ["query"]=> NULL
>   ["stmth"]=> NULL ["conn"]=> NULL }

here is my dbconfig.inc.php code:

```
session_start();
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') . ':' . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('**********'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('**********'));
define('DB_BASE', 'project');
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') . ";dbname=" . DB_BASE . "", "********", "*********");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
}
include 'classes.inc.php';

$project = new projecteg($conn);
```

here is the code for st&com.php file:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
include_once "includes/dbconfig.inc.php";
$status_replies="";
$status_list="";
$statusui_edit="";
$isowner="";
$is_friend="";
$statusdeletebutton='';     
$reply_delete_button="";
$load=  (int)($_POST['load'])*2;
var_dump($conn);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($project);
echo '<br>';
function hashtags($dat) {
$regex="/#+([a-zA-z0-9._-]+)/";
$dat1=  preg_replace($regex, '<a href="hash_sys.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $dat);
return $dat1;

}
function taggingsys($dat) {
$regex="/@+([a-zA-z0-9!._-]+)/";

$dat1=  preg_replace($regex, '<a href="home.php?u=$1">$0</a>', $dat);
return $dat1;

}

function ff(&$s) {
  //$conn=""; 
  //require_once 'includes/dbconfig.inc.php';

    $output=array(); 
   // $friends=array();
 //$project= new \projecteg($conn);
  // $totalids=array();
 $verify_friend=array();
foreach ($s as $i=> $r ){

   //array_push($friends, $r);
  $r["friend_one"] == $_SESSION['uname'] ? $friends[]= $r["friend_two"] : $friends[] = $r["friend_one"]; 
  echo '<pre>';var_dump($friends);echo '</pre>';   
  $verify_friend= $project->totalids($friends[$i]);  
  /* foreach ($friends as $v) {
       echo '<br><h1>';       print_r($v); echo '</h1></br>';         

        echo '<br>';
                     //   var_dump($verify_friend);
  // array_push($totalids, $verify_friend);     

        }

    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($verify_friend); echo '</pre>'; */
   array_push($output, $verify_friend);

}
   return $output;
}

$f = array();
$stmt=  $conn->prepare("select friend_one, friend_two from friends where (friend_one=:session OR friend_two=:session) and accepted='1'");
$stmt->bindparam(":session",$_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();
$f=$stmt->fetchAll();

$ids=  ff($f);

foreach ($ids as $i=>$v){

    $id=$v[$i]['user_id'];

    //fetch user_id from update table in db and inject it to the feed query.
    $totalUpdates=$project->totalUpdates1($id,$load);   
    $total_sess_count=$project->totalupdatescount($id);

    foreach ($totalUpdates as $j=>$row1) {

                $updateid=$row1['update_id'];

                $account_name=$row1['account_name'];
                $u_id=$row1['user_id_u'];
                $author=$row1['author'];
                $post_date=$row1['time'];
                $title= stripslashes($row1['title']);
                $data= stripslashes($row1['update_body']);
              $data1=  hashtags($data);
              //$data1=  taggingsys($data0);
              $pic=$project->viewByUname($author);
              $uid=$pic['user_id'];
         $datemade = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($post_date));
           $avatar=$pic['avatar'];
          if ($avatar!=""){
          $feed_pic='user/'.$uid.'/'.$avatar;
      }  else {
          $feed_pic='img/avatardefault.png';
          }
  //other lengthy logic
```

here is the class logic:

```
<?php

class projecteg
{
    private $_db;
    public $query;
    public $stmth;
    public $conn;

    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->_db = $conn;
    }

    public function totalids($friend)
    {
        try {

            $sql2 = "select user_id from user where uname=:session or uname=:friend and activated='1'";
            $stmth = $this->_db->prepare("$sql2");//Check here syntax of $db 
            $stmth->bindValue(":session", $_SESSION['uname']);
            $stmth->bindValue(":friend", $friend);
            $stmth->execute();
            return $stmth->fetchAll();

        } catch(PDOException $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

how do i make my method and conn to work.

Comment: The error says it is on line 46 yet you don't share that with us, hard to debug what we can't see.

Comment: In your code, there are no calls to the `totalids()` method. You need to show that code.

Comment: Can't help you: `Call to a member function totalids() on a non-object `. nowhere in your code do you actually CALL `totalids()`. and you haven't posted anything that actually has 46 lines in it.

Comment: sorry abt that its a lengthy code, let me include it @MarcB

Comment: `//$project= new \projecteg($conn);`  I'd start by uncommenting that line if you want to do `$project->totalids($friends[$i]);` later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `$project` inside a function `ff()` without passing it in or declaring it inside the function so it doesn't exist inside the scope of that function. Do some research on scope that should help you out. But for now you need to pass in `$project` to `ff()` if you want to use it. Something like this:

```
function ff(&$s,$project) {
...
}
$ids =  ff($f,$project);
```

That is assuming you want to use the `$project` you have already declared. If not you will need to create a new instance inside the function like Patrick-Q said in the comments.

Comment: thanks will take your advice